# Problemas com apk no intel xdk

Tags: html5, intel-xdk, cordova-plugin

Estou com dificuldades em gerar uma `apk` no `intel xdk`, ele esta gerando certo, porém meu aplicativo comunica com um servidor da `amazon`, que coleta os dados direto do servidor.
No `intel xdk` ele funciona certinho comunica uma beleza, porem quando gero o `apk` e instalo no celular simplesmente não comunica com internet o app. O que pode ser? alguém ja passou por isso?

Obrigado

Comment: I suspect your whitelist rules (possible CSP rules) are the culprit. Please read the documentation here > https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-cordova-whitelist-rules-with-intel-xdk <